# Django - how to filter a queryset on multiple reverse lookup matches

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-filter

I have two models: `Order` and `OrderStatus`.

Don't worry about Order, but OrderStatus has the following fields:

```
order = models.ForiegnKey(Order)
status = models.CharField (choice that can be either ORDERED, IN_TRANSIT, or RECEIVED)
```

OrderStatuses are created when the Order changes status, so initially there's just an `ORDERED` status, then later an `ORDERED` and `IN_TRANSIT` status, then later an `ORDERED`, `IN_TRANSIT`, and `RECEIVED` status all exist as foriegn keys to one Order. This is to keep track of timings, etc.

**I want to find all Orders which have all three statuses.** In other words, all orders that have been received and are valid because they have the other two statuses.

This is returning an empty set:

```
Order.objects.filter(Q(orderstatus__status=OrderStatus.ORDERED) &
                     Q(orderstatus__status=OrderStatus.IN_TRANSIT) &
                     Q(orderstatus__status=OrderStatus.RECEIVED))):
```

... but this is working fine:

```
Order.objects.filter(orderstatus__status=OrderStatus.ORDERED)
             .filter(orderstatus__status=OrderStatus.IN_TRANSIT)
             .filter(orderstatus__status=OrderStatus.RECEIVED)
```

What's the difference here? Is there any way to simplify? I thought this was what Q objects are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means a query where all the fields are required

```
Order.objects.filter(Q(orderstatus__status=OrderStatus.ORDERED) &
                         Q(orderstatus__status=OrderStatus.IN_TRANSIT) &
                         Q(orderstatus__status=OrderStatus.RECEIVED))):
```

This means that the third filter is applying on the result of second filter and the second filter is applying on the result of first filter

```
Order.objects.filter(orderstatus__status=OrderStatus.ORDERED)
             .filter(orderstatus__status=OrderStatus.IN_TRANSIT)
             .filter(orderstatus__status=OrderStatus.RECEIVED)
```

If you want to do something where you want to get the `Order` objects if their status is `ORDERED`,  `RECEIVED` `OR` `IN_TRANSIT` you can also do something like this

```
Order.objects.filter(orderstatus__status__in=[OrderStatus.ORDERED, OrderStatus.IN_TRANSIT, OrderStatus.RECEIVED])
```

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. Any way to simplify that triple filter?

Comment: what exactly do you want as the output? Do you want the `Order` that contains all three status? Is there a many to many on that Status or how is it connected?

Comment: Yes, is it possible to find that with a single filter?

Comment: don't you think there are only two filter, RECEIVED is twice in your query